# Interaction forces always depend on positions only through the distance, therefore conservative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, galilean-relativity, conservative-field

Suppose that two point masses $A_1,A_2$ are in interaction with each other, resulting in forces $F_1$ (acted upon $A_1$) and $F_2$ (acted upon $A_2$). Let $\bf{x}_1$,$\bf{x}_2$ be their respective positions in space. It is a fundamental assumption of Newtonian mechanics that interaction forces depend only on the positions and the velocities of the two objects: $$F_1=F_1(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\dot{\mathbf{x}}_1,\dot{\mathbf{x}}_2), \\ F_2=F_2(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\dot{\mathbf{x}}_1,\dot{\mathbf{x}}_2).$$

Suppose that the forces do not depend on the velocities; then we can write $$F_1=F_1(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2), \\ F_2=F_2(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2).$$
Now we can invoke symmetry considerations, following from [Galileo's Relativity Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance). The laws of mechanics are translation-invariant, therefore the forces must depend only on the relative position $ \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 $. They are also rotation-invariant, therefore the forces must depend only on the distance $\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|$, and lie on the line connecting the two point masses. Finally $F_2=-F_1$ from Newton's third law.

Overall, one can write $$F_1=f(\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|)\frac{ \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 }{\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|}, \\ F_1=-f(\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|)\frac{ \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 }{\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|}$$ for some scalar function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $F_1,F_2$ are conservative: $U(\| \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2 \|)$ is the potential function, where $U'=f$. In conclusion, the only way interaction forces between point masses can be non-conservative is if they depend on the velocities (e.g. Lorentz force).

**Is everything I just said correct?** because it seems like a quite important observation to me, yet I haven't seen it in any text.

Comment: the only way interaction forces between point masses can be non-conservative is if they depend on the velocities or explicitly time depending

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664983/

Comment: If the forces depend on velocities only, then they cannot be expressed in terms of the derivative of a potential function - meaning they are non-conservative by definition.